Duplicates error when i tried to use google-translate-api android studio
I try to build app on android studio with google translate api,
I add the line
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 34
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.27.0' // this line
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}

to build.gradle and then when I tried to run the project(after sync) i got that error
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
I tried to change the line to
implementation libs.google.cloud.translate
but it caused the same...
type here
I expect to see that there is no error this case. this is the latest version of android studio android 14
